# Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class - Common causes ... final class

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

i am using pointcut regex pattern to monitor execution of some of my methods. one of the Util classes i am using is declared final. because of that i get the error while Spring config is loading up.

1. i am not able to write a pointcut regex pattern to exclude final classes. i am unaware of the syntax and not able to find one to avoid final on net too.
2. can i avoid this problem in a way without using pointcut pattern (to exclude final classes) at all ?

i am using @Configuration and defining my config in there.

Comment: Please give an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am running testNG cases which extend AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests. when they start and load the config, while scanning they throw the CGLIB error.
i am using @ Configuration and defining a JdkRegexpMethodPointcut @Bean in there with included/excluded patterns.

Comment: if i put the pattern with the name of the final class in exclude patterns, i do not get exception anymore. so i know it is the final Util class which i wrote having some minor utility methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i bypassed my problem by providing a ClassFilter to the jdk regex pointcut and exclude all the final classes using modifiers.